# Make: how to force immediate expansion of a variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following GNU makefile snippet:

```
# this code is not under my control
A = aaa
B = bbb

# this code is under my control
A += $B

B = ccc
# Prints "aaa ccc".  I would rather "aaa bbb".
$(info $A)
```

The issue is that since `A` is initially created as a deferred variable, the value of the RHS of the `+=` is taken as a deferred value.  Is there something like `A += $(immediate B)` that I can use?

The following somewhat gets there:

```
TMP := $B
A += $TMP
```

but is not an option since this will be in an include file, and gets used several times (in the context of a non-recursive make system).  So `TMP` would get clobbered each time.

**UPDATE**

A little more justification.  This is a non-recursive build, and variable `d` holds the name of the directory being processed.  An include file is invoked for each subdirectory, setting up some variables.  For example:

```
$d.LIBS += $($d.target_dir)/lib.a
LD_FLAGS += $($d.LIBS)
```

The problem here is that `d` is ephemeral, with its value changing as soon as the next directory is processed.  `LD_FLAGS` and, for that matter, `$d.LIBS` may need to remain as deferred variables but `d` needs to be evaluated immediately here.

Comment: Please update your example with something that shows the issues you're having with including the file, it's hard to visualize what's going on.

Comment: You don't say if you need `A` to continue to be deferred or not.  If you don't mind it becoming an immediate variable you can just use `A := $A $B`

Comment: @user657267 The above snippet is a complete runnable make script.  The actual use case is a non-recursive make, with an include file that is invoked for each directory, $B being the name of the current directory.

Comment: @MadScientist That may work in a practical sense, if there is no other solution.  But I'd prefer that A remain deferred, if it had been defined that way in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind `A` becoming immediate, then you can just use this:

```
A := $A $B
```

If you want `A` to continue to be deferred, but to expand `$B` immediately, you can use `eval` because `eval` expands its argument:

```
$(eval A += $B)
```

This will expand `$B` first, so you get `A += bbb`, then evaluate that.

If you want some aspects of the value expanded and others not, just escape the not-to-be-expanded content:

```
$(eval LD_FLAGS += $$($d.LIBS))
```

I should say, though, that usually the things you're trying to do are handled more by constructed variable names based on the target name, so something like:

```
LD_FLAGS += $($@_LDFLAGS)
```

or whatever.